# How to share resources between projects in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

The project I'm working on at work is a webapp on the [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) Framework. We're using [xsbt web plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin) as well. There's a "core" project, which contains the vast majority of the functionality; my current goal is to create two "distribution" projects that add a different set of classpath resources to the "core" project. The problem is that I either 1) can't get the "distribution" projects to run, or 2) Get them to run, but the required resource doesn't seem to be there.

**What I've tried**

Here's an abridged version of my `project/Build.scala`:

```
lazy val core = Project("Core", file("core"))
  .settings( /*some dependencies, resolvers, webSettings */ )

lazy val app1 = Project("App1", file("app1"))
  .aggregate(core)
  .settings( /*the same settings as core */ )

lazy val app2 = Project("App2", file("app2"))
  .aggregate(core)
  .settings( /*the same settings as core*/ )
```

Then in the directory structure for both `app1` and `app2`, I have a file at `src/main/resources/aFileINeed`. The core application is using the `class.getResource` approach to load the file from the classpath.

**Problems**

If I try to run one of the distribution projects, using `container:start`, it does not detect the required file in the classpath. Also, it claims that `src/main/webapp` is not an existing directory (that folder is included in the core project, as it is required by the xsbt web plugin).

**How can I get these projects to "merge" their resources?** I expected that using `aggregate` or `dependsOn` in the `Build.scala` project definition would handle that for me, but it apparently doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I'm doing. I create a global 'resources' directory in the root of the project, and then the following variable:

```
    lazy val globalResources = file("resources")
```

And then in every project's settings:

```
    unmanagedResourceDirectories in Runtime += globalResources
```

For projects that use the xsbt-web-plugin or some other library that imports it you'll have to use the stronger

```
    unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += globalResources
```

Beware that using this solution your projects will potentially have muliple resource directories and AFAIK if you define the same file twice `compile:copy-resources` is going to be angry at you.

Comment: If `globalResources` eventually grows in complexity, you can also graduate it to a `Project` and reference its resources from other [projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855318/1080804)