# SBT: Access managed resources of a subproject?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

In an SBT Plugin, I'm trying to access to managed resources of subprojects.

Here is the build file:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val appName         = "demo"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.jruby" % "jruby-complete" % "1.7.1"
  )

  val widgets = play.Project("widgets", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("widgets"))
  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("demo"))
    .dependsOn(widgets)

}
```

I'm working in an SBT plugin defined in plugins.sbt.

Now, I need to use resources files from the subproject (widgets) during compilation of the parent project (demo).

So far the closest I've got to is the buildDependencies settings key - but I'm only getting ProjectRef objects, and the only information is the build base and the project id. I couldn't find a way to get to that project's resources  directory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with writing plugins, but at least in your `build.sbt` you can [define the resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604399/1080804).

Or, again in the `build.sbt` you can [create a "common" project that others reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795226/1080804), like:

```
lazy val common = (project in file("common"))
  .settings(
    Seq(
      includeFilter in unmanagedResources := new SimpleFileFilter(_.getCanonicalPath.startsWith((sourceDirectory.value / "main" / "resources").getCanonicalPath))
    )
  )
```

Then other code (e.g. a Task) could reference this like:

```
lazy val doSomething = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Does something useful")
lazy val doSomethingSetting = doIt := {

  val resourceDir = (resourceDirectory in common in Compile).value
  println(resourceDir)

}
```

So your other projects could run this or [reference that directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604399/1080804)

Hopefully there's a straight forward way to implement one of those solutions for a plugin vs a build?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not believe this is possible. I was trying something similar but found the following in the documentation:

> Note: At runtime, all plugins for all builds are loaded in a separate, parent class loader of the class loaders for builds. This means that plugins will not see classes or resources from build definitions

See: [SBT Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins.html)

Comment: The quote is referring to classes and resources that are available from the plugin class loader.  This means `Class.forName(..., getClass.getClassLoader)` and `getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(...)`.  Also, it is only talking about classes and resources defined for the build definition.  That is, the ones in `project/` and not the main project.  

A plugin can still use settings/tasks as usual to get the `File`s corresponding to the resources and classes of a project.