# how to get the sub project path in sbt multi project build

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to get the location of sub project in multi-project build in sbt. But I am able to get only the root project directory.

```
lazy val copyToResources = taskKey[Unit]("copies the assembly jar.")
private val rootLocation: File = file(".").getAbsoluteFile
private val subProjectLocation: File =  file("sub_project").getAbsoluteFile.getParentFile
lazy val settings = Seq(copyToResources := {
val absPath = subProjectLocation.getAbsolutePath
println(s"rootLocation:$subProjectLocation $absPath, sub-proj-location: ${rootLocation.getAbsolutePath}")
 })
```

Output:

```
 rootLocation:/home/user/projects/workarea/repo /home/vdinakaran/projects/workarea/repo, sub-proj-location: /home/vdinakaran/projects/workarea/repo
 rootLocation:/home/user/projects/workarea/repo /home/vdinakaran/projects/workarea/repo, sub-proj-location: /home/vdinakaran/projects/workarea/repo
```

directory structure:

```
repo
   |-- sub_project
```

As a work around , I have added the sub_project folder using the rootLocation. But why the file("sub_project") is not returning the path ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define your subproject like this

```
lazy val subProject = project in file("sub_project") // ...
```

then you can get its path using the scoped `baseDirectory` setting:

(outdated syntax, pre sbt 1)

```
baseDirectory.in(subProject).value.getAbsolutePath
```

(new unified syntax)

```
(subProject / baseDirectory).value.getAbsolutePath
```

And in the sbt console:

```
> show subProject/baseDirectory
```

About the problem with your code (beside that you mixed up root and sub-project in the output) is the usage of relative paths. Sbt documentation on [Paths](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Paths.html) explicitly says

> Relative files should **only** be used when defining the base directory of a Project, where they will be resolved properly.
>
> Elsewhere, files should be absolute or be built up from an absolute base File. The `baseDirectory` setting defines the base directory of the build or project depending on the scope.