# How do I convert baseDirectory to a String in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing a `Build.scala` file for **sbt** which needs to use the base directory of the project.
I can't figure out how to get the project path as a String from `baseDirectory`.

If using `build.sbt` it works doing

```
thePath := baseDirectory.value
```

but when I try to call value from a `build.scala` I get the error

> value can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=,
>   ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting

Apparently, `baseDirectory` is a `Def.Initialize[File]` instance but I have looked at its code [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/sxr/sbt/Settings.scala.html#sbt;Init;Initialize) and I do not fully understand it.

Comment: Can you please provide a more wide example of what you are trying to achieve within `Build.scala`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `baseDirectory.value.getAbsolutePath` does the trick. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766783/how-to-get-the-sub-project-path-in-sbt-multi-project-build) to see how to get the path for sub-projects.

Comment: I think this answers the question. And the link is to a _related_ SO question: complementary, but not essential to the answer.